# Pass arguments to contact.php

Tags: simplemodal

How can I pass variable to contact.php that I can echo on form.  I can pass through the form to the email recipient, but, I'm at wits end trying to print to form.

For example, I'd like to set $somevariable="This will be my default Subject", pass the variable through the contact.js and be able in the contact.php receive the variable and use the for the value="#somevaraible" for the subject on the form.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just pass the value from PHP to the document and then use javascript to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like ajax, which will allow you to communicate directly from javascript to PHP scripts.  The easiest is probably jquery's implementation of ajax.  You are able to pass parameters to your PHP application.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For example, I can pass any param I want to map.php. With GET this would be the equivalent of calling "map.php?param1=strvalue1&param2=strvalue2" (in the example)  I can then capture these values in PHP by using something like $param1 = $_GET['param1'];  In the example, whatever the PHP file displays in response to this is then written to an element with the ID of write.  All of what I just mentioned can occur after a page has loaded.

You can call the javascript below as many times as you like with whatever javascript functions you see fit.  Just keep in mind it will continue to replace whatever is in ID of write, you just need to update that snipplet of code to update the value of your field.

You need to make sure you include Jquery's library when using this like:

```
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "map.php",
        type: "GET",
        data:{ param1 : "strvalue1",
               param2: "strvalue2"
                },
        dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {
        $( "#write" ).html( msg );
        });
</script>
```